# Unable to parse JSON string error in my Phonegap project

Tags: javascript, android, json, cordova

I'm having problems while getting JSON from PHP. The code in below is works:

```
[{
        "vehicleId": "1",
        "status": "Running",
        "position": "x",
        "battery": "25",
        "distanceTravelled": "123",
        "destination": "y",
        "freeSeats": "2",
        "speed": "32"
    }
]
```

But, my new version of my code it is comes like that (without quotes in number values) and it gives a parse Json error and it doen't shown anything.

```
[{ 
        "vehicleId": 1,
        "status": "Running",
        "position": "x",
        "battery": 25,
        "distanceTravelled": 123,
        "destination": "y",
        "freeSeats": 2,
        "speed": 32
    }
]
```

I checked the format at jsonlint.com and it is valid. The error in log in Eclipse is:

```
05-09 21:37:25.536: E/Web Console(336): SyntaxError: Unable to parse JSON string at file:///android_asset/www/MobileMan.js:37

    34  xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);
    35  xmlhttp.send();
    36  var json = xmlhttp.responseText; 
    37  obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

I also tried the Javascript code in my computer on Chrome and everything works fine. I couldn't resolve the problem. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: http://json.parser.online.fr/ `SyntaxError: Unexpected token v` ...

Comment: You have a typo in the question where you're missing a `"`. This must not be in your actual code since you said it passes `jsonlint`

Comment: quote is missing for `vehileId` tag. It should be `"vehicleId"` instead of `vehicleId"`

Comment: @squint I'm sorry I just forgot " part while asking question,  and it is still doesn't work

Comment: Are you using jQuery in your project ?

Comment: @RomainBraun yes I am using

Comment: Then you should use $.parseJSON() instead.

Comment: @RomainBraun I tried it, $.parseJSON() returns null object.

Comment: Isn't it already a json object ?

Comment: did you ever solve this? I'm having the same problem, going crazy here

Comment: add var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json);

Comment: Have you the answer for this, am stuck in this from morning. Please Help !!

Answer (score 0):

Well if the parser is throwing error then it means the value provided to parse is not a pure JSON object.

About [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

- **JSON.parse** - Parse a string as JSON, optionally transforming the value produced by parsing. If the string to parse is not valid JSON, a SyntaxError exception is thrown.

On the other hand, about [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

- **JSON.stringify** - Convert a value to JSON, optionally replacing values if a replacer function is specified, or optionally including only the specified properties if a replacer array is specified.

Hence in your case, you firstly need to convert the result obtained to a JSON object and then try to parse it.

```
a = [{ 
        "vehicleId": 1,
        "status": "Running",
        "position": "x",
        "battery": 25,
        "distanceTravelled": 123,
        "destination": "y",
        "freeSeats": 2,
        "speed": 32
    }
];

var b = JSON.stringify(a);
var c = JSON.parse(b);
console.log(c)
```